# tomcat clustering and load balancing issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, web, cluster-computing

I have web application that is using a configuration file and it is loaded once on application start up in application context

For configuration application also has a administrator panel that updates configuration file, this administration panel takes the backup of current version and updates the changes done and also updates memory copy (in application context) of configuration

Util now I was only using one instance on tomcat server but now I need to deploy the application on two different tomcat servers both running on different machines with load balancer installed on a third machine

now with two tomcat instances (both tomcat 6) and load balancer in place how can configurations updates be made available on both tomcat instances

example:

If adminsitrator logs in and tomcat instance 1 is hit and administrator updates configuration in instance 1 how can I update instance 2 with same updates that are done in instance 1.

Does tomcat support this or I have to do it in my program by explicitly hitting the other instance?

I cannot update or change any configuration of the load balancer

Comment: You may want to look at [context replication](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/cluster.html#Context_Attribute_Replication). Also your configuration should be stored in a single location accessible to both instances, for instance in a database.